# Treating an array of structs containing `x` as an array of `x`

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I have an array `a` of struct `S` that includes member `x`.

I also have a function `f` that accepts an array of `x` (without the struct).

```
//file1
struct S {
    int x;
    //other members...
};

S s[1000];

//file2
void f(int x[]);
```

I could modify `f` to accept an array of `S`, but this pattern is making my code less modular as I have to propagate the definiton of `S`, and making my functions less generic. I could loop over `a` and copy each `x` to a new array, but `a` might be large. Is there a way to keep modularity and efficiency?

For instance, maybe `f` could also accept the size of the struct and use it for pointer arithmetic, therefore treating an array of arbitrary structs that contain `x` as an actual array of `x`?

Comment: How would you guarantee that memory alignment matches? What if the `struct S` is extended to have other attributes?

Comment: `is making my code less modular` then make `f` a template?

Comment: @KamilCuk template won't help here. If you do `T x[]`, it still wouldn't allow you substituting `T` with `struct S` and `int` interchangeably.

Comment: @littleadv `How would you guarantee that memory alignment matches?` You can use a static_assert.

Comment: `it still wouldn't allow you substituting T with struct S and int interchangeably.` No, I was thinking of `void f(T arr[]) { std::cout << arr[idx].x << '\n'; }` or `void f(T arr[], int& (*T::getx)()) { std::cout << arr[idx].*getx(); }`.

Comment: @littleadv You would pass to f a pointer to S.x[0] and the size of the struct. f would add the size of the struct to &(S.x[0]) to get &(S.x[1]).

Comment: @KamilCuk  you still can't call such an `f` with a parameter which is `int[]`.

Comment: Why exactly do you *want* a function that does something to each `x` member of the structs, and doesn't care about the rest of them? What actually *is* your `f`? Do you have a real use case in mind, or is this an academic exercise?

Comment: @William right, that would be the only way around it

Comment: Well, then an adaptor would be better. `void f(T x)` where `T requires int& operator[]`

Comment: @KamilCuk not enough

Comment: @littleadv Here -https://godbolt.org/z/ezxGqjzE7  a small example that takes just `void f(T x)` and is called with array and with adaptor of array of S.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel S contains a timestamp and datapoint, and f is a component of a Discrete Fourier Transform that operates a vector of datapoints.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to keep modularity and efficiency?

There is a way: Templates.

Since modifying `f` seems to be an option, you can achieve your goal by making it a function template. It could accept any range of integers. You can then adapt the array of `S` to pass it into `f`.

Example:

```
template<class Range>
void f(Range&& x);

// usage
void example()
{
    // using with s
    auto s_to_int = [](S s) { return s.x; };
    f(std::views::all(s) | std::views::transform(s_to_int));

    // using with an array of integers
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    f(arr);
}
```

---

> S contains a timestamp and datapoint, and f is a component of a Discrete Fourier Transform that operates a vector of datapoints.

If you're going to do numerical operations on the array of S, then this seems inefficient.

You're likely better off by using an array of data points, and a separate array of timestamps where the indices of each array correspond to each other.